# Visual Studio Code transparent image preview without checkerboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, the default image preview renders transparency with a checkerboard pattern, where the light squares match the editor's background color (see screenshots below). I would like to visualize images without the checkerboard and have the background as the editor's background color.

A user already asked the same question in the [VSCode GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52717), but the thread is closed due to a lack of interest. I would like to see if anyone came with a solution or if other users have the same concern to re-open the discussion and propose a toggle to remove the checkerboard if needed in the user settings.

[image: VSCode Linux transparent checkerboard GitHub light]
[image: VSCode Linux transparent checkerboard solarized light]

Comment: Please remove the visual-studio tag if the question only concerns Visual Studio Code. Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are 2 completely different pieces of software.

Comment: Done, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: then you don't know if the image HAS transparency

Comment: This is why I suggest adding a toggle. I am making scientific images with transparent background to avoid having a huge contrast between the figure background and the editor (in dark mode). Disabling the checkerboard would be nice in this case.